# Why the $total shows 40 and not 20?

Tags: laravel

There are 1 registration with 2 participant in a conference, so the database is like below.

registrations table

```
id     conference_id      user_that_did_registration
1         1                           1
```

participants table

```
id   registration_id     registration_type_id
4           4                   1   
5           4                   1
```

registration types table

```
id     name     conference_id      price
1     general           1           10
```

I want to get the total price of the registration with id "1" that should be 20 because there are 2 participants each one associted with the registration type "1" that has the price 10.

I have this code but the dd($total) shows 40 instead of 20. Do you know why?

```
$registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with(['participants.registration_type',
    'participants' => function ($query) use ($regID) {
        $query->select('id', 'registration_type_id', 'registration_id')->where('registration_id', $regID);
    }
])->find($regID);


if ($registrationTypeDetails->user_that_did_registration != $user_id) {
    return redirect('/');
} else {
    $total = 0;
    $type_counts = [];
    foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
        $name = $p->registration_type->name;
        if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
            $type_counts[$name] = 0;
        }
        $type_counts[$name]++;
    }

    dd($registrationTypeDetails->participants);

    foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $participant) {
        $total += $participant->registration_type->price * $type_counts[$name];
    }

    dd($total); // shows 40 not 20
}
```

The $registrationTypeDetails shows:

```
Registration {#290 ▼
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "participants" => Collection {#299 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => Participant {#306 ▼
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#311 ▶}
          ]
        }
        1 => Participant {#308 ▼
          #relations: array:1 [▼
            "registration_type" => RegistrationType {#311 ▼
              #attributes: array:11 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "name" => "general"
                "price" => 10
                "conference_id" => 1
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You probably should be redefining `$name` in your second loop. `$name` will be set during the first loop, and will be the same value for all loops in the second unless you redefine it.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes this, but for debugging purposes, I'd var_dump the variables until I found the mistakes. I'd start by var_dumping $registrationTypeDetails.

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$registration_type
".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once, assuming you have `hasMany` relation between `Registration` and `Participant`. Similarly `Participant` has `belongsTo` relation with `RegistrationType`

```
$registration = Registration::with('participants', 'participants.registration_type')->find($regID);

$totalPrice = $registration->participants->sum(function ($participant) {
    return $participant->registration_type->price;
});

echo $totalPrice;
```

Laravel Collection Sum https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum